# Why condition statement is not executing?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I want to read data from my MySQL database.

The `if myresult:` statement is not returning anything. It seems that this statement is not working or password checking is not happening.

```
@app.route('/stdLog',methods=['POST','GET'])
def stdLog():
    if request.method=='POST':
        mycursor=mydb.cursor()
        pwHash=bcrypt.generate_password_hash(request.form['password'])
        sql="select * from student where name=%s and password=%s"
        val=(request.form['name'],pwHash)
        mycursor.execute(sql,val)
        myresult=mycursor.fetchall()
        if myresult:
           print("logged in")
    return 'ok'
```

Comment: Try debugging your code with `print` statements. Check if `myresult` has something in it.

Comment: it prints nothing but return 'ok'

Comment: Does it return `ok`? Or it doesn't print anything?

Comment: And if you're trying to get the result on a webpage, your current program will always return `ok`.

Comment: I am assume that you're trying to view your result in a webpage, by executing the `flask service` and you're not returning anything if your `if` block gets executed. Please change your `print` to `return`.` if  myresult:
        return "logged in" `

Answer (score 0):

`print` statements don't reflect into the service. Print statement only works with a console or `REPL`. In your program I assume that you want to return `logged in` on a webpage, and for that you need to change your print statement to return as following:

```
@app.route('/stdLog',methods=['POST','GET'])
def stdLog():
    if request.method=='POST':
        mycursor=mydb.cursor()
        pwHash=bcrypt.generate_password_hash(request.form['password'])
        sql="select * from student where name=%s and password=%s"
        val=(request.form['name'],pwHash)
        mycursor.execute(sql,val)
        myresult=mycursor.fetchall()
        if  myresult:
            return ("logged in")
    return 'ok'
```

Now if your `if` condition fails, it would result `ok`, which is a bad thing. You can add an `else` block to make your program work better.

Comment: If I store password without hashing then it works properly but after hashing it does not execute if block.

Comment: It seems like you have some issue with your hashing function, this it isn't returning a True.